# Sitemapindex containing nearly identical sitemaps? - is that a problem

Tags: web-crawlers, sitemap

I am currently in the process of migrating content from one domain to another domain,
In this case I have some difficulty on how I should map the sitemap.

I currently have a sitemapindex file, which is split by culture.
In my case I have a culture that is partially migrated, so some of the
content exists in the old domain and the new domain.

I am not sure about what content exists in either domain,
so to ensure that all pages are listed in the sitemap,
my suggestion would be to have a nested sitemapindex, within the existing one.

Which point to a sitemap generated from the old domain and one from the new domain.  But can the sitemapindex file be nested?

it would look something like this

```
sitemapindex-root
-> /da/sitemap.xml // example of fully migrated
-> /es/sitemapindex.xml //example of partially migrated
    -> /es/sitemap.xml
    -> /sitemap/es.xml
```

An alternative approach in case nested sitemapindex is not possible is to keep them at the root level

```
sitemapindex-root
-> /da/sitemap.xml // example of fully migrated
-> /es/sitemap.xml //example of partially migrated
-> /sitemap/es.xml //example of partially migrated
```

The partially migrated sitemaps will have overlap, as  in the same url
will be listed in both sitemaps -  will that be an issue?

I only found it to be an issue in case it is in the same xml file, no issue in case it is in different xml files.

Comment: Isn't that going to be very confusing for users?  Why not migrate the content first and then switch over the domain redirection?

Comment: We won't make it until deadline - hence alternative solution